# MariaDB take long time to execute

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I have a table with 500 rows of data in "MariaDB-10.3.1"

When i run "TURNUCATE, ALTER, DROP, RENAME" operations take a long time for execution and nothing happend, i wait 30 minutes for 500 rows of data but not finished execution.

anyone can help me to solve the problem?

Comment: The table metadata is almost certainly locked. While the slow operation is running, open another terminal and run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`. That will show you what state your slow operation is in (probably waiting for metadata lock), and what other queries are running that could be causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
SELECT concat('KILL ', ID, ';') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE `db` IN (DATABASE_NAMES);
```

and kill all process then my query worked.

Thank you all.